# Event generation in database based on time

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am wondering if there is any method available to implement event trigger based on time. Lets say i want to deleted/modify a record in a certain time span for example in two days/48 hrs automatically,do i ve to implement something via code for checking it everyday? or database provide any functionality that makes life easier to check the time automatically to trigger the event. Thanks in advance.

Regards
OS

Comment: Do you want an answer for `SQL Server`, `MySQL`, or both?

Answer (score 2):

You usually want a cron job, for that. Optionally with some kind of scheduled_jobs table.